# Angular2 bind on meta tag odd result

Tags: angular

When, using angular2, I bind to a meta tags attributes I get some odd results. For example, if I have the following binding.

```
 <meta name="{{x}}">
```

and x gets resolved to "hello", the HTML output will be

```
 <hello></hello>
```

Or, when I add a second attribute, this becomes an attribute on the hello tag. I have found quite some information about angular2 not being able to deal with meta tags in a good way, but this particular issue is odd. Any idea if some kind of binding is possible?

(Note, I tried other ways of binding as well, in other tags it works, meta tags just messes up)

the code

```
  @Component({
selector: 'head',
template:
        `
             <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
             <meta name="{{testVariable}}">
             <base href="/">
             <title></title>
        `
```

})

The output (testVariable is helloworld)

```
 ...
 <body>
<helloworld></helloworld>
<base href="/">
```

Using the latest version of angular2

Comment: this [github issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7301) related to what you want

Comment: Would you mind sharing more code? A plunker that demonstrates what you try to accomplish would be great.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I shared some more code

Comment: Is `head` your root component. Please create a plunker. It's really hard to see what you're doing with these code fragments ([Plunker template](https://plnkr.co/edit/zUSPUx?p=info))

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the issue. [**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/ypu2so?p=preview)

This approach also won't buy you much because when Angular adds the root component your `<head>` tag will be wiped and replaced by the template of your root component. There is also no way to add a `<body>xxx</body>` element to the template of your root component because `<head>` can't have a `<body>` element.

Using `<html>` as selector still has the issue that your `<head>` tag will be purged (CSS, script tags, ... everything removed).

What you probably want is something like the [Title](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/platform/browser/Title-class.html) service. Currently `<title>` is the only `<head>` tag that is directly supported, but more is planned.

In the meantime you can take the `Title` service as template and build your own that supports more tags or you can change the tags imperatively `document.head.querySelector...`